Free fields in Weinberg QFT vol.1
Background:
In  section 5.1 Weinberg discusses free fields. He had shown that for interaction of the form, $V(t) = \int{d^3x \mathscr{H}(\mathbf{x},t)}$ if $$U_0(\Lambda,a) \mathscr{H}(x) U_0^{-1}(\Lambda,a)= \mathscr{H}(\Lambda x+a)$$ and $$\left[ \mathscr{H}(x),\mathscr{H}(x') = 0 \right]$$ for $x-x'$ space-like then the $S$-matrix is Lorentz invariant. He builds $ \mathscr{H}(x) $ out of creation and annihilation fields so that it transforms like a scalar and the S-matrix satisfies the cluster decomposition principle.
The  annihilation and creation fields are defined respectively as
\begin{align}
    \psi_l^+(x)&=\sum_{\sigma n} \int{d^3p \, u_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) a(\mathbf{p, \sigma, n })} \\
    \psi_l^-(x)&=\sum_{\sigma n} \int{d^3p \, v_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{p}, \sigma, n )}
\end{align}
with coefficients $  u_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) $ and $v_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) $ such that,
\begin{align}
    U_0(\Lambda,a) \psi_l^{\pm}(x) U_0^{-1}(\Lambda,a) &= \sum_{\bar{l}}{D_{l\bar{l}}(\Lambda^{-1}) \psi_l^{\pm}(\Lambda x +a) }
\end{align}
It can be seen that the D matrices furnish a representation of the homogeneous Lorentz group. In the above transformation rule, using the transformation rule for creation and annihilation operators Weinberg proceeds to find the coefficients $  u_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) $ and $v_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) $. The final result is that,
\begin{align}
    u_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) &= (2 \pi)^{-3/2} e^{i p.x} u_l(\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) \\
    v_l(x;\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) &= (2 \pi)^{-3/2} e^{-i p.x} v_l(\mathbf{p},\sigma, n) \\
    u_l(\mathbf{q},\sigma, n) &= (m/q^0)^{1/2} \sum_{l}{D_{\bar{l}l}(L(q)) u_l(0, \sigma, n)} \\ 
    v_l(\mathbf{q},\sigma, n) &= (m/q^0)^{1/2} \sum_{l}{D_{\bar{l}l}(L(q)) v_l(0, \sigma, n)} \\
   \sum_{\bar{\sigma}}{u_\bar{l}(0,\bar{\sigma}, n) J_{\bar{\sigma} \sigma}^{(j_n)}} &= \sum_{l}{ \mathscr{J}_{\bar{l}l}u_l(0,\sigma, n)} \\
   \sum_{\bar{\sigma}}{v_\bar{l}(0,\bar{\sigma}, n) J^{(j_n)*}_{\bar{\sigma} \sigma}} &= \sum_{l}{ \mathscr{J}_{\bar{l}l}v_l(0,\sigma, n)} 
\end{align}
where $L(q)$ is the standard boost which takes a massive particle (of mass m) at rest to momentum $q^\mu$ and $J_{\bar{\sigma} \sigma}^{(j)}$ is the angular momentum matrix in the representation $D^{(j)}(R)$ and $\mathscr{J}_{\bar{l} l}$ is the angular momentum matrix in the representation $D(R)$.
The doubt
I couldn't understand the following paragraph in Pg.196 of Weinberg QFT vol.1.



I do not understand

Why the representation $D(R)$ must contain the spin $j$-representation among it's irreducible components?
How $u_l(0, \sigma , n)$ and $v_l(0, \sigma , n)$ describe how the spin $j$-representation is embedded in $D(R)$?
His statement that


each irrep of proper orthochronous Lorentz group contains any given irrep of the rotation group atmost once, so that if the fields $\psi^{\pm}_l(x)$ transform irreducibly then they are unique upto a scale.


Don't use images/screenshots for text (or math). Instead, type the relevant passage.
